# transparency in Javafx with blend effect

Tags: javafx

i always want to have a background video and a foreground that can be also a video or an image
or buttons/text.
I used a stackpane and played around with setBlend - does not work.
A stackpane with background video (MediaView) and Buttons in front works (without blend settings).
Is there an option to mix foreground/background (also with videos/images in foreground)

```
package h;

import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.BlendMode;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BlendEffectExample extends Application {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // Drawing a Circle
        String path = "/home/h/git/repositories/hm/src/main/resources/VID_20210320_142327.mp4";

        String path2 = "/home/h/git/repositories/hm/src/main/resources/VID-20210320-WA0001.mp4";

        // Instantiating Media class
        Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());

        // Instantiating Media class
        Media media2 = new Media(new File(path2).toURI().toString());

        // Instantiating MediaPlayer class
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer(media2);

        // Instantiating MediaView class
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        MediaView mediaView2 = new MediaView(mediaPlayer2);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        mediaPlayer2.setAutoPlay(true);

        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.setFill(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0, 0.5f));
        circle.setCenterX(590);
        circle.setCenterY(50);
        circle.setRadius(25);

        // Instantiating the blend class

        Image image = new Image(new File("/home/h/ownCloud/Photos/Duc/img_1e36477988c71b4e8891a7732f2b89af.jpg")
                .toURI().toString());

        ImageView imgView = new ImageView();
        imgView.setImage(image);
        Rectangle2D viewportRect = new Rectangle2D(170, 80, 120, 300);
        imgView.setViewport(viewportRect);

        Group group = new Group();
        // group.setBlendMode(BlendMode.COLOR_BURN);
        group.getChildren().add(mediaView);
        // group.getChildren().add(mediaView2);
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        stackPane.getChildren().add(mediaView2);
        stackPane.getChildren().add(imgView);
        stackPane.setBlendMode(BlendMode.SRC_OVER);

        // Creating a scene object
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, 1000, 800);

        // Setting title to the Stage
        stage.setTitle("Blend Example");

        // Adding scene to the stage
        stage.setScene(scene);

        // Displaying the contents of the stage
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

best regards

Comment: please make the code a [mcve] (by replacing the local file references with resources on the internet)

Comment: @Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
URI uri1 = null, uri2 = null;
try {
uri1 = new URL("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4").toURI();
uri2 = URI.create("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4");
  } catch (MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} 
Media mediaUri1 = new Media(uri1.toString());
Media mediaUri2 = new Media(uri2.toString());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(mediaUri1);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer(mediaUri2);}
}

Comment: please edit the question (instead of posting changes in a comment :)